# How to get estimated views / real time views from youtube api?

Tags: google-api, youtube-api

I know how to get subscriber count and total views, but how is it possible to get views for last 60 minutes or 24 hours? You can find these inside youtube analytics with a browser.

Comment: All the supported metrics are found in [Video reports](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/channel_reports#video-reports) particularly in the "Basic stats" section. With regard to time, check the Dimensions in the [Understanding report tables](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/channel_reports#understanding-report-tables). To actually use these properties, use [Reports.query](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reference/reports/query).